# Configure SSH key based not working on Windows

Tags: windows-10, ssh, iphone

I have a shared laptop with Windows 10 at home that I would like to use SSH to log into from my jailbroken iPhone using the NewTerm and OpenSSH tweaks

I used this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wx7WPDnwcDg) to set it up. The SSH connection works but when I try to add a pub key it does not ask for the passphrase of the key instead it ask for the user password

I have followed all the instructions:

1. I installed and launched the OpenSSH server on Windows.
2. I created a private/public key with `ssh-keygen` on the iPhone and `scp` the pub key to Windows.
3. Created and secured the `administrators_authorized_keys` and instead of `Administrators:F` in the file I had to use `Administrateur:F` since I use a French Windows.

   Now the SSH command output `testuser@windows_ip's password`
4. I set the `sshd_config` to `PubkeyAuthentication yes` and `PasswordAuthentication no`.

After all that the ssh command on the iPhone output `Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive)`.

What am I missing?

---

**EDIT 2**: Here are [the server side logs](https://nopaste.net/StbOJxpesk). I also updated the log for the [client](https://nopaste.net/qtEz13FnRZ) to match the server side

Comment: If you're trying to SSH into Windows, the private key should be installed on the server and the public key used by the client.

Comment: Provide the verbose logs from both the client and the server. I suspect you’re using the wrong username. Without those logs we can’t diagnose your problem. So an appropriate [edit] is required.

Comment: @harrymc so in step 2 I need to send the  id_rsa (not .pub) to Windows then I use it in step 3 to fill the administrator_authorized_keys ?

Comment: @Ramhound done !

Comment: Yes, but the key needs to be installed. Try to follow [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_keymanagement).

Comment: @harrymc ok I have started over using the article provided. The ssh-add $env:USERPROFILE\.ssh\id_rsa is added successfully but the ssh testuser@windows_ip $remotePowershell output an Permission denied

Comment: @Grez - Your client can’t find an appropriate key to use based on your logs

Comment: You also did not include the server verbose logs. I am looking to see if the server properly identifies the username your using

Comment: @Ramhound finally found how to get the logs on the server ... I edited the question with the 2nd client logs and the server logs

Comment: “Bad permissions. Try removing permissions for user” - Fix your permissions on the key.

Comment: @Ramhound Oh that solved it ... I messed up I marked Administrateur:F instead of Administrateurs:F thx

Comment: You should submit an answer.

Comment: @Ramhound done thx again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I had to restart from the beginning because I changed my phone and had to start again and had problems recreating the setup

Here is how I did it

1. `ssh-keygen` on the client side
2. `scp` `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub` to `C:/Users/X/.ssh` for `id_rsa` and `C:/ProgramData/ssh` for `id_rsa.pub`
3. Use Powershell in administartor with

```
Get-Service ssh-agent | Set-Service -StartupType Automatic
Start-Service ssh-agent
Get-Service ssh-agent
ssh-add $env:USERPROFILE\.ssh\id_rsa
```

4. Using cmd in Administartor

```
cd C:/ProgramData/ssh
type id_rsa.pub >> administrators_authorized_keys
icacls administrators_authorized_keys /inheritance:r /grant "Administrateurs:F" /grant "SYSTEM:F"
```

note here Administrateurs needs to be what ever Administrateurs means in your windows default language so Administrators for english

5. In `Services` Start/Restart `OpenSSH Authentication Agent` and `OpenSSH SSH Server`
6. ssh user@PC_ip
7. If it works delete `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub`